# Как из строки вытащить часть и к ней применить условие?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть данные вида:

[image: Data]

Из них я могу вытащить contactname (вернее даже отдельно имя и фамилию):

```
SELECT
    C.contactname,
    SUBSTRING(C.contactname, 1, CHARINDEX(', ', C.contactname) - 1) AS Lastname,
    SUBSTRING(C.contactname,
                 CHARINDEX(' ', C.contactname) + 1,
                 LEN(C.contactname) - CHARINDEX(' ', C.contactname)) AS Firstname
FROM [Sales].[Customers] AS C
```

Как теперь применить тут условие чтобы исключить те имена (Firstname) которые начинаются на "М"? (такие как Michael и пр.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        C.contactname,
        SUBSTRING(C.contactname, 1, CHARINDEX(', ', C.contactname) - 1) AS Lastname,
        SUBSTRING(C.contactname,
                     CHARINDEX(' ', C.contactname) + 1,
                     LEN(C.contactname) - CHARINDEX(' ', C.contactname)) AS Firstname
    FROM [Sales].[Customers] AS C) A
WHERE A.Firstname NOT LIKE 'M%'
```